# posting in json format

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, post

Sorry for poor english :)

I was trying to post form in json format for the restapi written in php/python. I cannot access posted data if i use json . See the scenario below

The code for non json post

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
     $.post(  
        "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/entry/?format=json",  
        {
        "body": "This will prbbly be my lst edited  post.",
        "pub_date": "2011-05-22T00:46:38",
        "slug": "another-post",
        "title": "Another Post",
        "username":"admin",
        "password":"admin"


        },  
        function(responseText){  
            $("#result").html(responseText);  
        },  
        "html"  
    );
  })
```

Server response

```
 Array
 (
 [body] => This will prbbly be my lst edited  post.
 [pub_date] => 2011-05-22T00:46:38
 [slug] => another-post
 [title] => Another Post
 [username] => admin
 [password] => admin
 )
```

Code for Json Post

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   var data = JSON.stringify({
    "body": "This will prbbly be my lst edited  post.",
    "pub_date": "2011-05-22T00:46:38",
    "slug": "another-post",
    "title": "Another Post",
"username":"admin",
"password":"admin"


});

 $.post(  
        "testpost.php",  
        data,  
        function(responseText){  
            $("#result").html(responseText);  
        },  
        "html"  
    );
  })
```

Server response

```
Array
(
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you havent assigned the value to any parameter, hence PHP won't be able to populate the `$_POST` array.

Assign it to a parameter, for example, `json`:

```
$.post("testpost.php", {json: data}, ...);
```

Then you will be able to access it with:

```
$_POST['json'];
```

Or if you use PECL, you can call [`http_get_request_body` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-get-request-body.php) to get the data.

Comment: eval(data) will do? or it will simply convert json back to object?? just getting curious :)

Comment: In PHP or JavaScript? In PHP, use `json_decode` and in JavaScript use `JSON.parse`.

Answer (score 1):

this is normal response, data must be an array/object of key value pairs or a properly encoded query string something much like key=value&key2=value2 ...
If you want to get the posted datas like you did server side you should read the input yourself something like that:

```
$jsonDatas = file_get_contents('php://input')
```

Easier way you can do in your js:

```
data = { json: JSON.stringify({...}) }
```

And then get the result in  $_POST['json'] serverside.

If you want you can check a class of mine to assist you working with json service with php serverside here: http://projects.jgotti.net/blog/15